# In C, can you modify a global variable in a function and then use the modified value in the same function later

Tags: c, global

Please give a simple example.
Thank you

Comment: Not if another function has modified the global variable. Then it will have a different value.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int x = 0;
void foo(void) {
    x += 1;
    printf("%d\n", x);
}
int main(void) {
    foo(); foo(); foo();
    return 0;
}
```